# Visual Studio publish a class library with dependecies of other packages as one DLL and/or nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, publish

**Notice**: yes I am aware similar questions have been asked before and I have explored these. Like ILMerge,IRepack, I tried to implement these for on Publish but that just does not work.

I have made a class library or two, which are common code used in other projects. The problem I have is when I try to publish this code to their retrospective output location (Because of company policy this is a different location)

The thing is when I publish this class library, the class library does not produce a single DLL/NugetPackage, what you should expect when you do a class library build. I thought this was standard in Visual Studio, why is this not the case?

Yes these class libraries do use some other packages like SeriLogger which I can kind of understand then but even DLL's are created I do not even technically use, like ASP.NET libraries. Authorization and authentication, which I do not use.

[image]

I have tried ILMerge and ILRepack, even the so called simple ones you did need to configure, which mind you the instructions are still not clear enough for it. Either too little or the information is not existing at all.

So if anyone can help me be my guest.